# SQL Database mirroring \ replication capabilities?

Tags: sql-server, replication, mirroring, master-master-replication

I've looked through the similar questions, but they are a little further down the line, more into details already.

While I'm still researching the concept of mirroring and what can and can not be achieved.

So I wanted to ask an opinion\suggestion\direction:

- We have a web app which is backed by an SQL DB (2014)
- We also have remote (far..) office which uses that web app
- The remote office uses our local HQ web server so the network delay is getting on their nerves

Ideally we would like to replicated the whole app environment (web server + db) to their region and have a "live sync" between these two environments.

Within the app itself - there is no provisioned functionality for this.

So I am looking into default SQL toolset or other 3-rd party solutions maybe which could help us set a mirror of the main DB in the remote region with live synchronization (if possible). We can survive a data replication delay (user in region 1 creates something while it gets to the region 2 within next 5 minutes).

It's fairly common situation and I want to understand if this can be achieved by SQL tools themselves or with some other 3rd party solution which will manage the replication\syncing?

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring won't do this...its one way.   You need to investigate either Transactional or Merge Replication for the two-way communication, if you want to stay in the SQL Server capabilities.   merge helps if you have bad bandwidth or network drops.   Both Tx and Merge have their own unique requirements that are well documented on Technet :)